# Get List of Files from FTP Folder with a Large Number of Files

Tags: .net

I am trying to get a listing of all the files in a ftp folder.  The problem is that there are about 96000 image files, so the directory listing times out.  Any thoughts on how I might use .Net (prefer VB.Net) to get the file details (modified date).  I want to get the information to allow me to sync the files.  While there may be a program out there to do this, this is only a temporary solution until we finish moving the files to our S3 Bucket.  Thanks.

Comment: can you possibly separate the files into folders? handling the timeout and then being able to process the folder's with a little less trouble. In a previous job we had a unix server that had many tens of thousand files in a folder (less than you have but still a lot) ... We ended up putting a small script on the server that would output the Listing to a file, zip it, then we'd retrieve it and parse.. (maybe that is an option)

Comment: Use wcf to pipe a dir into a text file and send it down.  Or WCF where you pass the last filename and get the next.  Or limit to like 1000 files a directory.  FTP past 10,000 is a problem.

Comment: Breaking the files into different folders wouldn't work since they are all products, named by the item sku, so categorizing them would be a pain.  Since I can access both sides of the process, putting the info into something I could download or access would be ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access both sides

Just pipe the dir into a file
Open a command

dir > dir.txt

Answer (score 0):

You can use codebehind to access the files.

```
For Each s In System.IO.Directory.GetFiles("/")
  Response.Write(s & "<br>")
Next s
```

You probably won't want to use response.write or the path "/", but you can access the files this way if the permissions allow.